# Python regex to handle numerics + %

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for a regex to handle these cases:

```
5.55%
555.555%
```

Essentially, any numeric followed by a period, then more numerics, then a percentage sign.

I am trying this regex:

```
"\d+\.\s*%"
```

but it does not appear to work.

Comment: did you mean `\d` not `\s`?

Comment: The part after the dot should be _exactly the same_ as before.

Comment: @Macattack Thanks that fixed it. Missed that somehow.